# create multi array php with two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays same like when var_dump:

```
$arr1 = array (size=2)
    0 => string '10:2' 
    1 => string '10:1'

$arr2 = array (size=2)
    0 => string '[{username:userA,email:userA@gmail.com'
    1 => string 'username:userB,email:userB@gmail.com}]'
```

Now, i want to result same below:

```
$result = array (size=2)
    '10:2' => 
         array (size=2)
            'username' => string 'userA' 
            'email' => string 'userA@gmail.com' 

    '10:1' => 
         array (size=2)
            'username' => string 'userB' 
            'email' => string 'userB@gmail.com'
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think that array, have to be fixed before that point

Comment: Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to join the 2 arrays.

Comment: Why are the elements of `$arr2` formatted differently? One has `[{` at the beginning the other has `}]` at the end. Why don't those characters appear in `$result`?

Comment: As @Barmar said, it seems like you want to parse the values of `$arr2` (usename and password) ! you aren't clear !

Comment: $arr2 is from a json...something weird there

Comment: Yeah @mansoulx, you right. It must `str_replace, substr` for same `$result`. Because im get string and `explode` to `$arr2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
// Turn string "key1:val1,key2,val2,..." into associative array.
function str_to_assoc($str) {
    $str = str_replace(array('[{', '}]'), '', $str); // Remove extranous garbage
    $arr = explode(',', $str);
    $res = array();
    foreach ($arr as $keyvalue) {
        list($key, $value) = explode(':', $keyvalue);
        $res[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $res;

$result = array_combine($arr1, array_map('str_to_assoc', $arr2));
```

It looks like `$arr2` came from improperly parsing JSON by hand (maybe using `preg_split()`?). If you do:

```
$arr2 = json_decode($json_string);
```

then you should be able to get your result with just:

```
$result = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: thanks for help @Barmar. It's JSON. Im using `$arr2 = json_decode($json_string); $result = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);` This is return same `$result`

Comment: Yeah, `json_decode()` is what I meant -- got a little confused between PHP and Javascript.