# Retrieve 4 numeric values to populate style tag using a Regular Expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a field value coming back from mysql for a style tag.

Example:

```
$data_style = "position:absolute; top:0px; left:700px; width:500px; height:400px; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; display: list-item;"
```

I need to change the following 4 "numeric" values on the fly...

```
top:0px; left:700px; width:500px; height:400px;
```

What is the best way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single `preg_replace` call can do that using **array as patterns and replacements**:

```
$data_style = "position:absolute; top:0px; left:700px; width:500px; height:400px;
 vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px; display: list-item;";

$patterns = array('/(top\s*:\s*)\d+(px)/', '/(left\s*:\s*)\d+(px)/', 
                  '/(width\s*:\s*)\d+(px)/', '/(height\s*:\s*)\d+(px)/');
$replacements = array('${1}10${2}', '${1}500${2}', '${1}300${2}', '${1}450${2}');

$data_style = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $data_style);
echo $data_style;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
position:absolute; top:10px; left:500px; width:300px; height:450px;
vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 500px; display: list-item;
```

Comment: This is really good, however I need to run each numeric value through an image ratio function to come up with the values to be set in this replacements array. From what I can tell this is hard coding the numeric value... When I preg_match the array I get back: array (size=3)
0 => string 'left:700px' (length=10)
1 => string 'left:' (length=5)
2 => string 'px' (length=2)

Comment: Not sure this is really hardcoding. You can feed input values in whatever way and populate `$replacements` array dynamically.

Comment: This is good stuff I didn't know you could use arrays in preg_match... So I changed patterns to this: $patterns = array('/(top\s*:\s*)(\d+)?(px)/', '/(left\s*:\s*)(\d+)?(px)/', '/(width\s*:\s*)(\d+)?(px)/', '/(height\s*:\s*)(\d+)?(px)/');

So that I could get the values and run a calculation on them...
Think I'll have to have your patterns for the preg_replace.

This is awesome though thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the style string to an associative array, using `explode` to split it at semicolons, then `array_map` and `explode` to split the elements at colons. Then I'd update the elements that need to be changed, and put it back together into a style string.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679711/create-multi-array-php-with-two-arrays/18679837#18679837) for a function that does the string->associative array conversion, although it uses commas rather than semicolons as the major delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Put into compact code, this is more or less what Barmar suggested:

```
$st="position:absolute; top:0px; left:700px; width:500px; height:400px; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; display: list-item;";
// turn $st into into an associative array:
$tmp=preg_split('/\s*;\s*/',$st);$a=array();
foreach ($tmp as $v) {$v=preg_split('/\s*:\s*/',$v);if (count($v)>1) $a[$v[0]]=$v[1];}

// apply changes to individual elements of array ...
$a['top']="234px";
$a['left']="345px";
$a['width']="456px";
$a['height']="567px";

// convert $a-elements back into string:
foreach ($a as $k => &$v) $v="$k: $v";
// join all the elements and show result
echo join("; ",$a).";";
```